# render html div content based on screensize

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website which has a video background. However, it does not show on ios device.(not sure if it will show on Android either.) Now I would like to change the load method like this:

If the device is not media(width >700), then render (div part=video.html) else the website just render novideo.html (a background image).

This div is in the middle  part of the index page.

Here is a [video example](https://designsupply-web.com/samplecontent/vender/codepen/20181014.mp4)

BTW, this is just a simple website without building on top of any frameworks. I also prefer to use javascript instead of jquery. How should I do it?  Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome, you should have a look to [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries)

Comment: Thanks @Greedo I looked at css and similar answers based on css, the css is from some other developer. But how can I do in html part?

Comment: Ok, I see some javacript code on the page you shared, I will try it now. thank you

Comment: Then I really think that you should contact the other developer as HTML and CSS are really related.. Another solution would be to use javascript to manipulate the CSS, but this can  result in really dirty code

Answer (score 1):

Hi referring to this article [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp#:~:text=Using%20Media%20Queries%20With%20JavaScript,tablets%2C%20phones%2C%20etc](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp#:%7E:text=Using%20Media%20Queries%20With%20JavaScript,tablets%2C%20phones%2C%20etc)).

HTML: You can include both the video and image in a containing div. Like this:

```
<div class = "media">
    <img id = "image"/>
    <video id = "video"></video> 
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    document.getElementById("image").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("video").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("video").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Comment: Thanks @Nguyen, I try it now. The thing is I have a div of background image as well as div logo on top of that background image. So actually two html components. But let me try it, thank you :). The video part has only one div though

Comment: That's alright. Just refer to all the class / id of the elements you want to show

Comment: Is it possible to  have two different html components? If media, then nonvideo.html else video html? like kinds of partial html?

Comment: I guess you're asking if it's alright to not have the containing element. As long as you can refer to the element you want to show / hide using its class or id, javascript can change the display for you.